# How to prevent Shapeless from providing Generic instances?

Tags: scala, shapeless

One of my projects relies on Shapeless for providing scalacheck `Arbitrary` instances. The problem I'm running into is that, once I bring the corresponding implicits in scope, *everything* gets `Arbitrary` instances, even classes for which the naïve approach does not work.

To take a concrete example, let's imagine the following class:

```
class Test(val i: Int, val b: Boolean)
```

Where `i` and `b` depend on each other - let's say `b` is `true` if `i` is odd.

Now, the first thing I found surprising was that the following compiles:

```
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Test, Int :: Boolean :: HNil]]
```

I'd made `Test` a non-case class precisely so that Shapeless wouldn't pick it up, but it still does, somewhat magically. Everything I'd read had led me to assume that only case-classes could be "turned" into instances of `HList`, but that apparently was a mistake on my part.

Since `Arbitrary` does not provide an export mechanism (a la [export-hook](https://github.com/milessabin/export-hook)) that I know of, I'm not sure how to lower the priority of Shapeless-derived instances, or how to prevent Shapeless from deriving instances for `Test` altogether.

Comment: You're using shapeless-scalacheck for derivation?

Comment: I'm not - writing the derivation code was trivial, I didn't even think to look whether something already existed. Does shapeless-scalacheck solve the issue?

Comment: @TravisBrown also, after checking, it turns out that there is no version that is compatible with both Shapeless 2.3.1 and Scalacheck < 1.13, so it's not currently a possibility for my project.